# Visual Studio 2012 - Files excluded from build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am publishing my first MVC app.

The api controllers and mvc controllers are not publishing.

**When I browse the website I am getting a 500 error : www.XXX.com/api/XXX not found.**

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to correct?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Even though I did not check the "Exclude files from the App_Folder", the folder did not copy over in the publish process.

Because of another Microsoft "Rube Goldberg" product, I had to manually copy the folder over.

While that solved the problem, I should not have to do that.